# Google Services Plugin searching the wrong google-services.json file for client after gradle update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

After updating gradle I am getting the `No matching client found for package name` error when trying to build our `release` build type.
We currently have one `google-services.json` containing the client for our release build and one containing the clients for all the other testing environments. We used to organize our files in the following way:

```
/src
    /{productFlavor}
        google-services.json
        /release
            google-services.json
```

This worked fine until we recently upgraded gradle to 5.4.1. Now when trying to build for release it seems like Google Services Plugin only searches the first file and dismisses the second.

When I deleted the `google-services.json` for the testing environments the release build type works again. Is there a way to achieve this with only two `google-services.json` files or do I need to have one for each build type located in a corresponding directory?

Comment: You need to have one for each build type located in a corresponding directory

Comment: thank you for your comment @Md.Asaduzzaman , do you have a source for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one `google-services.json` for each build type located in a corresponding directory or have to provide **default** one. 
Quoted from [official doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)

> The `google-services.json` file is generally placed in the `app/`
>   directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module). As of
>   version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor
>   specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are
>   valid:

```
// dogfood and release are build types.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
    ...
```

> When product flavors are in use these more complicated directory
>   structures are also valid.

```
// free and paid are product flavors.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/paid/google-services.json
    src/release/free/google-services.json
    ...
```

Comment: Either this documentation is misleading, or I'm doing something wrong. In my observation, the "default" `google-services.json` always overrides the more specific flavored ones. So maybe those directory structures are "valid", but in my experience the flavored JSONs will never be actually picked in presence of `app/google-services.json`.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Have you solved the issue? I'm facing the same situation and the "default" json file always override the flavor ones